# Unable to disable touchpad

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo G580 laptop. I recently did a full re install of windows, which got rid of all the crapware that was pre-installed.

Sadly, it also got rid of the Synapics touchpad driver.

I tried to re-download them directly from [the website](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS031456). However, when I installed it I got this error:

[image]

Before I formatted my laptop I could hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because those drivers are not for the G580, they are for the IdeaPad U310 and U410 and their Touch variants. How did you decide on that driver anyway?

You want the [drivers for the G580](http://support.lenovo.com/en_VN/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT073548). Note that your laptop comes with either a Synaptics or Elan touchpad, and there are multiple standalone drivers for each as well as multiple combined Elan/Synaptics driver packages for the touchpad.

Unfortunately they are all pretty darn big, so you may have to waste a bunch of bandwidth and time figuring out which one works. Your best bet is to try the latest [Synaptics driver](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS037358) and work your way backwards.